# Could not load class | Spark-submit Intellij

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, spark-submit

I know this was asked here before but my case is a bit different I think.

I have a working simple project in Intellij

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAmWQ.png)

when I run through Intellij the program works fine and i can see results but whenever i export as a jar to run locally through spark-submit it fails with error "failed to load class"

Im running using : `spark-submit --class com.CarbonEmission --master local[*]  MyPath\TestSparkJar.jar`

Below is my sbt :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXqOi.png)

I've been stuck over this for some days now I hope someone can help.

Comment: if you copy paste stuff here instead of screenshots - people will be able to help faster

Answer (score 0):

The required --class file is not added in exported jar. Please extract and see the file